# call inArray in Angular JS instead jQuery method using rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

```
var index = $.inArray(photo, $scope.photoSrcList);
```

inArray pointing to jQuery inArray. But we needed Angular js inArray.

our application js is

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require angular-file-upload-shim
//= require angular
//= require angular-file-upload
//= require angular-ui-bootstrap-tpls
//= require angular-ui-date
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: See this http://java.dzone.com/articles/angularjs-different-ways-using.

Comment: Actually we have load angular method instead of jQuery method. So please help how to load Angular method?

Answer (score 0):

i'm a big fan [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) for searching through arrays.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use JS native `indexOf` or an `Array.prototype.includes` with [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)